# Which one of several identically named JavaScript functions is actually called?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm trying this quiz in the Chrome console: [Quiz](http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/)

I can't understand why the answer for this code is 2

```
 (function f(){
          function f(){ return 1; }
          return f();
          function f(){ return 2; }
        })();
```

Which f is called in this line   `return f();`? 
What is the sequence of the functions?

Comment: Those questions are yours or from the quiz? What was your answer?

Comment: The one that is defined the last within the scope is the one that returns.

Answer (score 7):

Functions are scoped (so a function inside an identically named function will override the outside function only when called inside it) and hoisted (so it doesn't matter where they appear in the code order), and the last one overwrites the first one.

Comment: first we declare the outer f and than call it? if yes,so i understand - both inner f are declared too.if not,when we execute the return f() only one function was declared..no?

Comment: Three functions are declared. Two get called.

Comment: Functions are always 'compiled' before the code runs so even tho it never gets to the second inner f() it has already overwritten f() before the first line of code has run.

Answer (score 2):

The problem and the answer to this is what many people call `Hoisting`.

Function declarations like this, are interpretated at `parsing time` not while executing. In simple words, the second function declaration `f()` overwrites the first one and therefore, the return value is `2`.

Hoisting happens on `function declarations` and `scoped variables` (declares with `var`). For instance:

```
(function() {    
    if( false ) {
        var hello = 10;
    }

    console.log( hello );
}());
```

The console.log will return `undefined` and will not throw an exception here. Even if the `if statement` is never encountered the variable was declared within the `function context`.

Answer (score 2):

At compile time declarations will be hoisted inside **f** scope. It would look like this at run time:

```
 (function f(){
      function f(){ return 1; }
      function f(){ return 2; }
      return f();
  })();
```

jAndy example would look like this:

```
(function() { 
    var hello;   
    if( false ) {
        hello = 10;
    }
    console.log( hello );
}());
```